# Service vs IntentService in a case of location tracking service

Tags: android, multithreading, location, android-service, android-intentservice

I read about the differences between `Service` and `IntentService`.

The main thing I read is that `IntentService` has a **Workerhtread** that the service runs in.

I need to have a service which run regardless of the application activities/ui, and keeps track of the user location.

The service will implement `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` and also `LocationListener`, and when running, will update a table with the location of the user all the time (until stopped).

Should I use `Service` or `IntentService`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An IntentService is meant to be a *fire and forget* service, for relatively short tasks that may be repeated. Another important distinction is that an IntentService stops itself when `onHandleIntent()`  returns. A regular Service doesn't stop unless you (or the android os) explicitly stop it.It sounds like you are planning on a long-running task that also runs when your app is not in the foreground.

In this scenario you definitely want to use a regular Service. You can still choose to perform the work in a separate thread by creating one inside the service and doing the work in there, but you don't necessarily have to. Remember that by default, a Service runs on the main thead.

Comment: thanks for the well explained answer. I think I'll go with the regular Service and maybe start a thread over there to track the location. One more question - I do have a Fragment with a google map on it, and i do want to inform the Fragment when the location has changed so it can draw the new location. I was thinking about doing this with broadcasting custom intents, and have a receiver listen to them in my fragment. Does that sound OK?

Comment: Yes that sounds ok